# Kali Linux on SD card not showing in boot loader

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I installed Kali Linux on my SD Card. The way I did it was:

- Make a bootable USB with the Kali Linux image burned on it
- Then use that USB to boot up the Kali Linux installer
- By the Kali Linux installer I selected the SD Card.

However, once I go to the boot manager and plug in my SD Card, it's not showing Kali Linux.

Comment: which version of the MacBook Air are you using? One of the Intel ones or the new MBA with the M1 chip?

Comment: @DavidAnderson That's not true. If done properly, the Mac startup manager can detect most flavors of Linux.

Comment: Apparently, after a discussion with [Todd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/370591/todd), I have come to the conclusion you used the wrong file to install Kali Linux. You should have used the [Kali Linux 64-Bit (Installer)](https://www.kali.org/downloads/).

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to fix this issue is to go to the Mac Terminal and type in the following:

First, type `diskutil list`. Find the Kali Linux bootable SD and find the identifier of the EFI partition. This will look something like `disk2s1`. Once you have that, type `sudo diskutil mount disk2s1`. Once it is mounted, go to Finder and press `Command + Shift + G` and type in `/Volumes/EFI`. Once you are in there, double click on the EFI folder, double click on the Boot folder, and rename `grubx64.efi` to `bootx64.efi`. Then, in Terminal, type `diskutil unmount EFI`. Then restart into the Boot Manager and see if you can find your Kali SD. It should appear as "EFI Boot".

You can also replace the icon of the Kali SD. First, make sure the image you want is in the .icns file format. Then go to the Mac Terminal and type `sudo diskutil mount diskidentifier`. Replace `diskidentifier` with the disk identifier from before. Then, type `cd /Volumes/EFI` and `rm .VolumeIcon.icns`. Then, type `cp /path/to/image.icns /Volumes/EFI/.VolumeIcon.icns`. Then, type `diskutil unmount EFI`.

The Kali Linux installer may not name the EFI partition `EFI` by default. If that is the case, you will need to use `NO\ NAME` instead. In the case that neither of those names work, use the disk identifier that you got previously.

[image]

Here is an image of what you might see in the EFI partition if it was called `NO NAME`. You can ignore all the contents of that partition except those in the `EFI` folder.

Now, your Kali Linux SD will work on any Intel Based, and maybe even an Apple Silicon based Mac.

Make sure you follow each step carefully or else you may end up ruining the SD and needing to erase it.

Good luck!

Comment: This applies to ready versions of Kali Linux. If you are trying to boot an installer, then make sure you use `dd` when "burning" the image to the SD card. If you use `dd`, then you should not have any issues booting it up normally using the Boot Manager.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I think you may be confused. There is an EFI/Boot folder if you look on a bootable version of Kali Linux, not the installer. There is a .VolumeIcon.icns file in the root dir of the EFI partition.

Comment: @DavidAnderson that's what I said. If the OP has installed Kali Linux itself onto the SD card, then my answer works. Use [this link](https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-2020.4/kali-linux-2020.4-installer-amd64.iso) as it's the actual installer. The OP didn't say that he/she used a live ISO. They said "Kali Linux Installer". Your testing is not using the correct image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117534/discussion-between-david-anderson-and-todd).